# Dynamically create directives from a loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-compile

I have a `main directive` that has an `array` on it's scope that contains data for constructing other `directives` that should be compiled and appended to the `main directive`.

The problem is that when I iterate through that array I only get the data from the last element in array,
so I can't properly bind respective data for each custom directive.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Of78TXfJfr8lmYLrTfOQ?p=preview)

main directive :

```
 angular.module('testApp')
   .directive('mainDirective', ["$compile", function ($compile) {

    return {
       template:   ' <div><p>Main Directive </p><div class="insertion-point"></div></div>',

       link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {

          var insertionPoint = element.find('.insertion-point');

          angular.forEach(scope.demoObj.panels, function (value, index) {


              var directiveName = value.type;

              scope.value = value;
              var directiveString = "<div " + directiveName + " panel-data=value ></div>";

              var compiledElement = $compile(directiveString)(scope);

              insertionPoint.append(compiledElement);

        });
    }


    }


}]);
```

directive to be nested:

```
 angular.module('testApp')
 .directive('nestedDirective', [function () {

    return {

       scope:{
         panelData:'='
       },
       template:' <div><p>Nested Directive </p>{{panelData.data.test}}</div>'
    }
}]);
```

data  looks like this:

```
                  $scope.demoObj = {

              panels:[
                {
                    id:'unique_id_1',
                    type:'nested-directive',
                    data:{
                      test:'test 1'
                    }
                },
                {
                    id:'unique_id_2',
                    type:'nested-directive',
                    data:{
                      test:'test 2'
                    }
                },
                {
                    id:'unique_id_3',
                    type:'nested-directive',
                    data:{
                      test:'test 3'
                    }
                }

            ]
        }
```

As far as I can understand , the compilation is not happening immediately in the `forEach` statement, that's why every directive gets the data from the object with the id `unique_id_3` (last element in array). Also all directives have isolated scope.

edit: I understand that in forEach I need to add the value to the scope so I can `pass` it to the nested directive isolated scope, and I understand that when the loop finishes `scope.value`  will be the last `value` of the loop, but I was under the impression that compile will `immediately` pass the value to the nested directive and be done with it.

So, when does the compilation happen?

How can I circumvent this limitation?

Comment: One thing: jqLite `find` is limited to tag names, so you might have a problem with your `insertionPoint`. Also, there are errors in your data object (e.g. missing quotes and unnecessary semicolons). Are the typos in pseudocode? Or are they problems in your real code too?

Comment: I have jQuery present on the page. Appending elements to `main directive` is not a problem.

Comment: Can you please setup a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) demonstrating the issue? I tried to for you, but there are too many issues with the code you've presented.

Comment: @MarcKline I've created the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Of78TXfJfr8lmYLrTfOQ?p=preview) and updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: I think your problem may have morphed based on the changes you made to your question code and Plunker, but, in any case, it seems that @YeLiu provides a working solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the link step of the `compiledElement` will happen in the *next* digest cycle, at that time, `scope.value` is the last value of the data.

The solution is to create different value properties on scope, like this:

```
var directiveName = value.type;
var valueProp = 'value' + index;
scope[valueProp] = value;
var directiveString = "<div " + directiveName + " panel-data=" + valueProp + "></div>";
```

[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/62WUw8TP7FOoHLxtArlL?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Please find the update code below. Rather than creating duplicate variable in scope Below is the solution. I have created [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vlflQj60xpEE8mqOtiVp?p=preview) for the same

```
angular.module('testApp')
 .directive('mainDirective', ["$compile", function ($compile) {

return {
   template:   ' <div><p>Main Directive </p><div class="insertion-point"></div></div>',

   link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {

      var insertionPoint = element.find('.insertion-point');

      angular.forEach(scope.demoObj.panels, function (value, index) {

          var directiveName = value.type;
          var directiveString = "<div " + directiveName + " panel-data=demoObj.panels["+ index+"]></div>";

          var compiledElement = $compile(directiveString)(scope);

          insertionPoint.append(compiledElement);
    });
}
}
}]);
```